Vue3 app doesn't work after deployment on Netlify
I've been working on Ryan Balieiro's foxy-template vue app and customized it a bit.
After changing a couple of things in the public/data folder and after adding a _redirects file containing /* /index.html 200 in the public folder of the repository, I tried to deploy it from Netlify's web interface.
More specifically, I deployed it from Github, by providing the following configuration:
.
My package.json looks like this:
{
  "name": "agency-template",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "deploy": "cd dist && cp index.html 404.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "vite": "^4.3.2"
  }
}

Sadly after trying to navigate to https://some-cool-name.netlify.app/portfolio I get an error and a blank page:

My vite.config.js looks like this:
// imports

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/portfolio',
  plugins: [vue()],
})

And router.js is just as the one in the template:
// ...

const data = useData()

export function createAppRouter() {
    const routeList = [
        {
            path: "/",
            name: "home",
            component: HomePage,
            label: "Home",
            faIcon: "fa-solid fa-home"
        },

        {
            path: "/policy",
            name: "policy",
            component: SecondaryPage,
            label: "Privacy Policy",
            faIcon: "fa-solid fa-hammer",
            props: {contentData: data.getPolicyData()}
        },

        {
            path: "/license",
            name: "license",
            component: SecondaryPage,
            label: "License",
            faIcon: "fa-solid fa-copy",
            props: {contentData: data.getLegalData()}
        },

        {
            path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
            redirect: "/"
        }
    ]

    return createRouter({
        history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
        routes: routeList,
    })
}

Working with versions:
"vue": "^3.2.47",
"vue-router": "^4.2.4"
"vite": "^4.3.2"

I already tried different deployment procedures (netlify's CLI and to deploy the dist folder manually) but nothing changes.
I also tried to leave the base directory of the app in vite.config.js empty but it seems to not work locally.
